# ControllerAdvice does not handle thrown Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

in my InvitationService file an exception thrown.

```
if (response != null && response.getStatus() == HttpStatus.SC_CONFLICT) {
        throw new UserAlreadyExistException("User Already Exists");
}
```

I defined an Custom Exception like this

```
public class UserAlreadyExistException extends RuntimeException{
    public UserAlreadyExistException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/invitations")
@Api(value = "Invitation APIs")
public class InvitationController {

 @Autowired
 InvitationService invitationService;

@PostMapping
@ApiOperation(value = "Invite tenant user")
public ResponseEntity<InvitationResponseDTO> inviteTenantUser(@RequestBody InvitationRequestDTO invitationRequestDTO) {

        invitationService.invite(invitationRequestDTO);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new InvitationResponseDTO("success"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and ControllerAdvice Class

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@ControllerAdvice()
public class ControllerExceptionHandler  {

    @ExceptionHandler(UserAlreadyExistException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserAlreadyExistException(UserAlreadyExistException ex) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

Question is, when an exception in service occurs, Still status code 500 thrown and when I debug, it does not enter through a breakpoint in the `ControllerExceptionHandler`

Comment: Trying to compare your code to mine, the only difference I'm seeing is that I use `@ControllerAdvice` without the empty parentheses.

Comment: If it does not stop for breakpoint in `ControllerExceptionHandler` then the controller advice isn't applying which could happen if it is not being instantiated. Are your package scans and package structure for all those classes setup correctly?

Comment: could you please attach the log when the error occur?

Comment: Probably ControllerExceptionHandler class is not being scanned by Spring ComponentScan. If that is the case, you should put this class where ComponentScan will find it. Maybe you could check if its being scanned and instantiated by spring. You can probably do that writing a default constructor for that class and calling a log.info('Class created'); inside it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but try to use `@RestControllerAdvice` instead of `@ControllerAdvice` on your exception handler class.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler  {

  @ExceptionHandler(value = UserAlreadyExistException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> 
  handleUserAlreadyExistException(UserAlreadyExistException ex) {

      return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am pretty sure that ControllerAdvice only handle exceptions of a RuntimeException nature, Exception is of checked nature and therefore must be explicitly caught and then wrapped as a Runtime for the ControllerAdvice to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to create exception handler like this (add WebRequest as input parameter to your method):

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {
  
    @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInputException(CustomException exception, WebRequest webRequest) {

       // your code here with breakpoint
       
    }
}
```